# How to set up jQuery TypeAhead to work with a large collection

Tags: c#, jquery, type-ahead

I would like to use jQuery TypeAhead functionality on my site.

I would like to use TypeAhead to fetch search results from Active Directory. Active Directory contains about 130,0000 records.

What do you think about this setup?

I am thinking I could create a job that runs nightly (or weekly) that dumps these AD records into SQL Server and query that.  Additionally, I am thinking about implementing some type of caching, so I am not querying AD or SQL every time.

Is there a more efficient way of structuring this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't say caching is the right term. You probably want to build indexes for queries such as `column like 'blah%'` and `column like '%blah'`. However, if you want queries `column like '%blah%'` you should simply use the full text search capabilities. See [CONTAINS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx).